# Eclipse EGit: fetch/push never ends

Tags: eclipse, push, fetch, egit

I use EGit 2.2 with Eclipse Juno.
So far everything has been more or less all right.

But once my team-mate has uploaded a number of large files (over 2 Gig) fetch and push operations never end for me. (My network connection is fast.)

How can I troubleshoot/resolve this?

Comment: can you do the operation also from the command line? just to check if it is a problem with `Git` or with `EGit`? I am assuming your network is fine and you don't have problem downloading large files (as you stated that your connection is fast)

Comment: @mardavi thank you for your advice. After doing some troubleshooting in vain I resolved the problem in a straightforward way: created a new Eclipse workspace and cloned the remote repository to the new workspace. It might not be the most clever way but seems to be efficient :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not a very experienced git user. So I resolved the problem a straightforward way: created a new Eclipse workspace and cloned the remote repository to the new workspace. Fetch and push operations work okay now.